# Should .cloned() be before or after .filter()

Tags: iterator, rust

Let's say that I have vector and I want just keep the even elements. I would need to used `cloned()` and `filter()`. For example:

```
fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<i32> = vec![1,2,3,4];

    let my_vec_1: Vec<i32> = my_vec.iter().cloned().filter(|&x| x % 2 == 0).collect();
    println!("{:?}", my_vec_1);

    let my_vec_2: Vec<i32> = my_vec.iter().filter(|&x| x % 2 == 0).cloned().collect();
    println!("{:?}", my_vec_2);

}
```

Both approaches work. Using `cloned()` after `filter()` seems a little bit more efficient. Because then I don't have to convert all elements of the iterator from `&T` to `T`, but only the ones that have been filtered. In my example that's half the elements.

However, I seem to see `cloned()` applied before `filter()`. Here is one example: [method.inspect](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.inspect)

I thought that maybe `.cloned()` has to be used before for types that don't implement `Copy` trait, but it does not seem to be the case: [nested vec example](http://is.gd/QRycon). Also, because filter uses `FnMut(&Self::Item)`, I don' think that should be a problem.

Are there advantages to using `cloned()` before `filter()`? Is this more of a stylistic issue? If so, is there preferred style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a matter of style.

The example of `inspect` is made to show-case `inspect`, that is all. It uses `.cloned` in an arguably silly way, but `cloned` was probably chosen because of its easy to understand semantic so as to create an easy to understand "complex iterator sequence".

---

So, `.cloned()` before or after `.filter(...)` ? As you mention, unless cloning is necessary for filtering (which would be surprising) the rule of thumb will be to clone after so as to minimize the number of cloned elements.

No style here, just a pragmatic performance assessment.

Answer (score 7):

This is an alternative to [Matthieu M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35358284/155423).

When you have small, `Copy` elements, you should `Clone` them as soon as possible. Cloning is nearly always free in these cases, but I have seen extra indirection confuse the optimizer. When you call `iter` on a container of integers, `cloned` should nearly always be the one to follow it unless you can merge it into the next call, eg. by an extra dereference in a call to `map`.

So in the case given, using `cloned` early is entirely sensible. It's true that this is a micro-optimization, but it's so easy to do and often makes the types simpler to work with, so I see no downsides to doing it.

In the future, [`copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) will likely become available as the preferred way to handle this.

---

When working with non-`Copy` types, where `Clone` might not be so cheap, delaying cloning is a much better default.

Comment: I disagree, `clone` should always be seen as "not cheap", compiler should do its job and optimize a "useless reference". If you put `cloned()` after even if you change your code you will always do the "good thing" but if you put it before you will need to not forget to move `cloned()` after.

Comment: I would agree if you use [`copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) where it's force that the type to implement copy.

Comment: @Stargateur I've added a note.