# How to get Vec<&String> after using iter().filter().collect() instead of Vec<&&String>

Tags: vector, reference, rust, iterator

I have a vector of Strings. I want to get two subsets from this vector:
strings with `"zzz"` and strings with `"bye"`.

The type of each subset is `Vec< && String>`. Which is a vector of references to a reference to original String. How can I get just `Vec<& String>`?

Code I am currently working on:

```
use std::string::String;
use std::vec::Vec;

fn main() {
    let a1 = String::from("hi");
    let a2 = String::from("bye");
    let a3 = String::from("zzz");

    let v_before: Vec<&String> = vec![&a1, &a2, &a3];

    // ref_a is a copy of v_before[0]
    let ref_zzz_a: &String = v_before[2];
    let ref_zzz_b: &String = v_before[2];

    println!("before: {:?}", v_before);

    // QUESTION: why can not this also be Vec<& String> ?
    // v_zzz is just like making  vec![ref_zzz_a, ref_zzz_b]
    let v_zzz: Vec<&&String> = v_before
        .iter()
        .filter(|&&element| element.contains("zzz"))
        .collect();

    let v_bye: Vec<&&String> = v_before
        .iter()
        .filter(|&&element| element.contains("bye"))
        .collect();

    let hand_made: Vec<&String> = vec![ref_zzz_a, ref_zzz_b];

    println!("v_zzz: {:?}", v_zzz);
    println!("v_bye: {:?}", v_bye);
    println!("hand_made: {:?}", hand_made);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=825d9220bfca83604d1adda9f35582b1))

One way would be to use `vector.into_iter()...`, but then I would not be able to run the second filter.

Also maybe this is just the way rust is? Due to automatic dereference maybe I should just not care that this is a `Vec<&& String>`? Would it lead to problems later?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`Iterator::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) to clone each reference instead of referencing them again:

```
let v_zzz: Vec<&String> = v_before
    .iter()
    .filter(|&element| element.contains("zzz"))
    .cloned()
    .collect();
```

Cloning a reference is cheap, since it is [implemented by dereferencing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/clone.rs.html#207-212).

---

*Aside: usually it's better to pass around `&str` instead of `&String`, as it's more flexible. When I see `&String` in Rust code, it stands out as something that is probably not intended, or can be improved.*

Comment: Thanks! And consider putting `.cloned()` after the `.filter()` due to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35354716/1073672

Comment: @user10607 Yes! I'd just spotted and changed that before seeing your comment. Although, I'm not sure it makes too much difference in the case, since it's only a pointer getting cloned.

Comment: @user10607 But also see the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35370500/493729) for that question, which applies here  (since a pointer is small and `Copy`)